Why are Orthogonal Trajectories of a curve UNIQUE?
Orthogonal trajectories are families of curves that intersect a given family of curves only at right angles. They can be obtained by solving the differential equation of the curve and applying the above condition.
While learning this, I had this thought: Why do we always get a unique family of curves, for example, the family of straight lines passing through the origin for the family of circles centered at the origin? Why not some family of.. parabolas that are orthogonal to the circles at the point of intersection?
Consider the family of circles, $ x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. Why isn't the family of coaxial circles given by $ (x - r)^2 + (y - l)^2 = l^2 $ also an orthogonal trajectory obtained when the differential equation is solved? This family of curves is indeed orthogonal to the circles. Why is only the unique family of straight lines $y = mx$ obtained when seeking the orthogonal trajectories?
I can think of many such examples.
Any help is appreciated!

What the differential equation formulation achieves is two independent families of orthogonal trajectories. But the second family you use uses the same parameter $r$ as the first and thus is not independent of that choice. In other words, each of your coaxial circles intersects orthogonally with exactly one of the centered circles; it does not intersect orthogonally with the others. By contrast, every line through the origin intersects orthogonally with every centered circle.
